# Filter CSV columns using pig

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

Hi stackoverflow community;

i'm new to pig, i have a CSV file that contains 5 columns with headers it's look like:

column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5

test1012   | test2045  | test3250   | test4865   | test5110
test1245 | test2047   | test3456   | test4234   | test5221
..........

i want to sort only column 1,3 and 4, but i dont know how to filter by column header.

if you could please point me to the right functions that will accomplish what I want to do, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you loaded this something like below (assuming it was using comma as delimiter) then you can just use the ORDER BY functionality.

```
myInput = LOAD 'myFile.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS
     (c1:chararray,c2:chararry,c3:chararray,c4:chararray,c5:chararry);
mySortedInput = ORDER myInput BY c1 ASC, c3, c4 ASC;
DUMP mySortedInput;
```

If you wanted to filter out just those columns then after the LOAD do the following.

```
myInputWithLessCols = FOREACH myInput GENERATE
     c1, c3, c4;
```

If I totally misunderstood and all that you were wanting to do was filter out the header row then you could do the following after the LOAD statement.

```
myInputWithoutHeaders = FILTER myInput BY c1 != 'column1'
    AND c2 != 'column2' AND c3 != 'column3' 
    AND c4 != 'column4' AND c5 != 'column5';
```

Comment: To remove the headers it would be better to use [CSVExcelStorage](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html).